# How to remove a specific border with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove the last border on the right as seen in the picture below. How would I go about in removing this?

[image]

My code:

```css
#headerlinks li, a {
    display: inline-flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    border-right: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
  <div id="headerlinks">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> Contact us </a></li> <!-- need to link and create contact us html -->
                <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
                <li></li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for -> ul li:last-child a {border: none}

Comment: Adding onto @VinuPrasad you should add `!important` like this: `ul li:last-child a {border: none !important;}`

Comment: You should also review your HTML for validity against the spec; it seems you have one too many `</li>` closing tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS : last child no border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690906/css-last-child-no-border)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add style for last of li that is `#headerlinks li:last-child, a`

```css
#headerlinks li, a {
    display: inline-flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    border-right: solid 1px black;
}
#headerlinks li:last-child, a {
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
 <div id="headerlinks">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> Contact us </a></li> <!-- need to link and create contact us html -->
                <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
                <li></li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the selector. `:last-child`

```css
#headerlinks li a {
    display: inline-flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

#headerlinks li:not(:last-child) a {
    border-right: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerlinks">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> Contact us </a></li> <!-- need to link and create contact us html -->
                <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove border from all a tag then simply remove border-right:solid 1px black from css

```css
#headerlinks li, a {
    display: inline-flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    border-right: solid 1px black;//remove this if border not req.
}
```

```html
<div id="headerlinks">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> Contact us </a></li> <!-- need to link and create contact us html -->
                <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
                <li></li><a href="#" style="border:none;">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: The OP clearly said that he wants to remove the border _from the __last__ `a` element_.

Comment: that is why I wrote "IF"  in description 

check code example

Comment: If he removes the border change, he would remove the border on _all_ `a` elements, not only the last.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "last-child" property in css, to remove border from last element. Also remove extra closing "li" element from html.

```css
#headerlinks li,
a {
    display: inline-flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    border-right: solid 1px black;
}

#headerlinks li:last-child,
a {
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerlinks">
    <nav>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#"> Contact us </a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```